# Rebase using github’s api

Tags: git, github, github-api

I have a `original_repo` with branch `master` that I forked to `fork_repo`.

Using github’s API, I can create a branch in `fork_repo` but I would like that this branch is up to date with `original_repo:master`.

It doesn’t seem possible to create a reference from an other repository (that would be quite strange), and I can’t find an endpoint to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following work-arround, not very satisfying, but at least it fulfils my need:

1. Create a pull request from original_repo:master to the fork_repo
2. Accept the pull request
3. Reset the head to remove the merge commit

Comment: I’m accepting myself it as nobody is reacting, but feel free to provide a better answer

Comment: Would using a 'rebase merge' avoid the need to reset the branch?